# Inkscape Suddenly Lost Color Shading on 3D Boxes

Tags: 14.04, inkscape

Using Inkscape in a Virtualbox VM with Ubuntu 14.04, oddly Inkscape is losing its color shading so that all I see are the dotted drag outline thingy's and not the color shading of the box sides, and not the lines. I tried selecting pieces of the box, as well as the whole box, and applying colors with Fill and Stroke, and nothing seems to work. I then did "apt-get update; apt-get remove --purge inkscape; apt-get autoremove; apt-get install inkscape" and it seems to have no effect.

What's the fix?

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Inkscape completely.
2. Open Terminal.
3. Do the following command:

   `mv ~/.config/inkscape ~/.config/inkscape.LAST`
4. Reopen Inkscape. The problem should have resolved itself by resetting options.